# RSS gallery as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rss

Here is my case - I have 10 movie clips on the view and in every movie clip I need to have a loaded picture that RSS. I've managed to get the first one loaded but I need the other 9 as well. Any ideas?

```
import com.adobe.xml.syndication.generic.FeedFactory;
import com.adobe.xml.syndication.generic.IFeed;
import com.adobe.xml.syndication.generic.IItem;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var rss:XML;
var rss_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://btvnews.bg/lbin/rss.php?section_id=16105?pic_size=300x158");


var rssLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(rss_url);
rssLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, rssLoaded);
var rssCount;
var rssCounter = 0;
var l = new Loader();


var loaderContext:LoaderContext;
loaderContext= new LoaderContext();

loaderContext.securityDomain=SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
loaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true;

Security.loadPolicyFile('http://img.bg.sof.cmestatic.com/crossdomain.xml');

function rssLoaded(e:Event):void
{

    rss = XML(rssLoader.data);

    var curImage = rss.channel.item[0].enclosure. @ url;
    l.load(new URLRequest(curImage));
    l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneIt);

    function doneIt(e:Event)
    {
        var bit:Bitmap = e.target.content;

        if (bit != null)
        {
            bit.smoothing = true;
        }
    }

    placer.addChild(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

After your rss load as you have loaded one images put a for loop for the item

```
for(var i=0; i < rss.channel.item.length;i++)
{
   var img = rss.channel.item[i].enclosure. @ url;
   //rest of the code to load the image and adding to stage
}
```